# Continuous probability distribution over integers?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, discrete-data

I have a random variable which can have any value from the set of natural numbers. For example, the probability of the random variable having a low value is higher than the probability of the random variable having a higher value.

So would this be a continuous probability distribution or a discrete probability distribution?

Comment: Do you have any ideas as to which it is and why?

Comment: I believed it would be a continous distribution because the probability would be a continuous value? does that make sense?

Comment: What is your definition of a continuous probability distribution?  What difficulty are you having in applying it to this situation?  BTW, much of your question makes no sense at all--please re-read the passage following "for example."

Comment: Whether a random variable has a discrete  or a continuous distribution depends on whether you can assign a probability to each of the individual possible values the random variable can take.

Comment: @Henry That does not seem like a distinguishing factor, because every continuous variable *does* have a probability assigned to every possible value it can take. Perhaps you meant to stipulate "*nonzero* probability"? But in that case many discrete variables would not actually qualify as discrete, either.

Comment: @whuber - I see your point.  Perhaps I should have said that for a discrete distribution these probabilities add up to $1$ while for a continuous distribution they are all $0$ (for intermediate cases the distribution may be a mixture)

Comment: @Henry That criterion works better.

Answer (score 14):

By definition your distribution is [discrete](http://www.henry.k12.ga.us/ugh/apstat/chapternotes/7supplement.html), because you can obtain all the values by counting.

Your confusion may stem from two sources. One is that often people assume that *discrete* also means *finite*. This is not true, e.g. the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) is defined on the non-negative integers, which is an infinite countable set $[0,+\infty)$.

Another source could be usage of computer-generated random numbers, or [pseudo random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)s. Since in computers even continuous variables, such as real numbers, are represented by countable sets (e.g. [IEEE double precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)), the PRNGs generate discrete sequences to approximate continuous variables. So, in some sense, everything we do in computers is discrete.

By "computers" I mean digital computers. Analog computers are different.